# Oracle APEX Link Builder - nothing showing up in set items for target page (to select from)

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I currently have two pages containing interactive reports, 4 and 6, using different tables. The field `WORD_ID` is the primary key for the table shown in page 4, and a foreign key for the table in page 6. I would like to make the `WORD_ID` column in page 4 a link so that when clicked the user is shown all entries in the page 6 table that have the same `WORD_ID`.

I've been trying to do this with the Link Builder:
[image]

But when I try to pick set items for the Name, I don't see any options to choose from (from what I understood, I expected to see things like `P6_WORD_ID`):
[image]

What might be the issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what sort of content you have on page 6, but nothing will appear in the link builder unless you have items defined on page 6 - and it's up to that page to use those items to do whatever filtering you need.

If you're linking to an interactive report page, you can automatically add a filter to the report using commands in the URL, as described in the documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmdb/linking-to-interactive-reports.html#GUID-86697C69-AD60-445A-90EC-7D7FE6F2217C

Comment: What do you mean by "defining" items? So far page 6 just contains an interactive report built from a table that has a column `WORD_ID`, among others.

Answer (score 0):

Linking from one page to another to restrict a query does not happen automatically on the basis of foreign key constraints in APEX. It can be *any* value or *multiple values* and data is passed from one page to another through items.

On page 6 your query will be something like

```
  SELECT <columns> 
    FROM <table>
   WHERE <some_column1> = :P6_WORD_ID;
```

`P6_WORD_ID` will be a hidden item on that page 6. After you have created page 6 like this, the link in the link builder on page 4 can be used. In the link, set item P6_WORD_ID to #WORD_ID#.

Comment: Where would I put this query?

Comment: That would be the source of your interactive report on page 6. If the source is a table then just use the where clause

Answer (score 0):

Create one more item as :P6_WORD_ID  in the Page number 6, and select the item using Page set Item and write a select query with this item filter in where condition such as below,

SELECT *
FROM <table_name>
WHERE word_id = :P6_WORD_ID;

[image]

Comment: How would I create the item  :P6_WORD_ID @Uthaman?

Comment: Please Open Page number 6 and If you have any region in the Body., simply create a new item and assign in your target item simple.